# How do I return the value of a key that is nested in an anonymous JSON block with jsonpath?

Tags: python, jsonpath

I am trying to extract the value of a key that is nested in an anonymous JSON block. This is what the JSON block looks like after `result`:

```
"extras": [
      {
        "key": "alternative_name",
        "value": "catr"
      },
      {
        "key": "lineage",
        "value": "This dataset was amalgamated, optimised and published by the Spatial hub. For more information visit www.spatialhub.scot."
      },
      {
        "key": "ssdi_link",
        "value": "https://www.spatialdata.gov.scot/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/4826c148-c1eb-4eaa-abad-ca4b1ec65230"
      },
      {
        "key": "update_frequency",
        "value": "annually"
      }
    ],
```

What I am trying to do is extract the value `annually`  but I can't use index because some other datasets have more keys under the `extras` section. I am trying to write a jsonpath expression that extracts `value` where `key` is `update_frequency`
So far what I have tried is:

```
$.result.extras[*].value[?(key='update_frequency')]
```

And still no luck.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Please share the remaining snippets of code of how you are calling the jsonpath.

Comment: A good practise is to create a serializable class that will represent your json architecture and simply deserialize or serialize your JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$.result.extras[?(@.key=="update_frequency")].value
```

Comment: Hi @CreepyRaccoon. The expression does work when I try it out on jsonpath.com but when I try to implement it in the code, I get the following error:
`jsonpath_ng.exceptions.JsonPathLexerError: Error on line 1, col 17: Unexpected character: ?`

It seems not to like the ? character. I am using Python btw

Comment: It's okay, I found out the issue. I was to import parse from the ext as follows:
```
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse
```
as mentioned [here](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng/issues/8)